# Why do I need to use import twice in Python/Pytorch?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I was following a Pytorch tutorial on Youtube, and when importing the relevant content/libraries, this was the code that the guy wrote:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
```

My question is: Why do I need to explicitly type the second line? Didn't the first one import *transforms* and *datasets* already?

The video I was watching for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yPxY2rOzs

I appreciate any help, and I'm sorry if this question is too obvious.

Comment: The second import makes `transforms` a shortcut for `torchvision.transforms` and `datasets` a shortcut for `torchvision.datasets`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to import them both.
You are right, the first import will get the entire library, but the second one is used as a syntax sugaring to be able to refer to the transforms and datasets objects directly, instead of referring to them as "torchvision.transforms" or "torchvision.datasets".